# Comparing two collection of points

Tags: geometry, statistics

I have a function $f(v)$ that takes a vector $v$ of numbers and spits out a function $c(t)$ which defines a looped path in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I also have another looped path in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is defined by the function $d(s)$. My goal is to come up with a vector of variables to give $f(v)$ that will yield a $c(t)$ that defines a curve that is as similar as possible to the curve defined by $d(s)$.

The function $c(t)$ is very difficult to reason with analytically. So, I have come up with a numerical solution to this problem.

I generate two sets of $M$ points that are uniform along the paths defined by $c(t)$ and $d(s)$, $S_c$ and $S_d$ respectively. Then, I compare the two sets and come up with an error value. A hill climbing algorithm tries to minimize this error value by tweaking the vector $v$.

To compare the sets, I need functions that go to zero as the curves come closer together. Note that the two curves are not parametrized in the same way, so it doesn't makes sense to compare them by using the inner product. I've thought of comparing center-of-mass, summing the minimum distances from each point in $S_c$ to $S_d$ and in $S_d$ to $S_c$, and using the maximum of those minimum distances. Currently I use a weighted sum of each of these.

Is there a better way to compare these curves?

(Any input on my approach here is also welcome.)

Comment: You're pretty close to reinventing the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Comment: Thanks! Now I have a name for one of my error functions :)